# Using cordova how can i get list of installed apps on android device?

Tags: android, cordova, install.packages

Any cordova pulgin ? What all things i need to import in .java file for getting installed apps on android?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late to answer the question, but I faced the same problem and tested both plugins `Deep Mehta` referred to in his answer. unfortunately none of them worked. The problem was when testing on devices that use company's custom UI such as HUAWEI, plugins he referred to were only returning the launcher itself!!

After more digging I finally found a nice plugin which works like a charm!The plugin is called `cordova-plugin-appavailability` and is available at https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Adarsh you can check this [plugin](https://github.com/KIvanow/installedApps) and this [plugin](https://github.com/jmrezayi2/Applist) out to get list of installed apps.

Comment: These two plugins would not work on customized UI devices such HUAWEI smartphones that are using company's custom launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Try [cordova-plugin-intent-list](https://github.com/nick-denry/cordova-plugin-intent-list) plugin. It returns applications list with Base64 encoded icons. Also you can get Intent label and package name (i.e. to start app with [this](https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp) plugin).